# Google Contacts and Free Busy API

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-contacts-api

I'm currently using a service called cloudiway to enable global address list sync and calendar free/busy sharing between EXO and GSuite. Our free/busy suddenly stopped working on the GSuite side and we are receiving the following message:

**Error:"unauthorized_client", Description:"Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.", Uri:""**

These are the API scopes i'm using and was wondering if i'm missing anything for calling calendar free/busy. I'm not too familiar with APIs so sorry if this isn't clear.

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts
**https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.freebusy**

Comment: Are you using a service account?

Comment: yes, i am using a service account. the service account has admin rights and password is up to date as well.

Comment: Can you provide your code so far?

Comment: This issue is resolved now. There was a dependency that was removed and that seemed to fix it. Thanks!